# TypeError: must be string, not unicode

Tags: python, unicode, pickle

I have this code:

```
...
msgdict = {'datafile': datafile, 'mapper': mapper, 'reducer':reducer}
msg = cPickle.dumps(msgdict)
print msg
```

The print msg I get this:

```
(dp1
S'mapper'
p2
(S's3n://myFolder/mapper.py'
p3
tp4
sS'datafile'
p5
(S's3n://myFolder/test.txt'
p6
tp7
sS'reducer'
p8
(S's3n://myFolder/reducer.py'
p9
tp10
s.
```

Then Im trying to get my content:

```
for i in range(count):
    m = q[0].read()
    # this print returns a object Message
    print m 
    # m.get_body()) returns the same of print msg above
    msg = cPickle.loads(m.get_body())
```

But Im having this errror:

```
msg = cPickle.loads(m.get_body())       
TypeError: must be string, not unicode
```

Someone knows how to solve this error?

Comment: Have you tried `repr()` all the strings?

Comment: what is `m`, `q` or `get_body`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to replace that line with the following:

```
msg = cPickle.loads(str(m.get_body()))
```

By casting `str()` to `m.get_body()`, it makes sure that if the string is unicode, it converts it to a string.